# Get django-paypal working with pycrypto?

Tags: python, django, encryption, paypal

I would like to use the button encryption in django-paypal, but it requires M2Crypto which will not build on webfaction servers.  Tech support at Webfaction told me that pycrypto is already installed on the system, but I am too dumb to translate from M2Crypto to pycrypto.

Can anyone tell me how to convert the following to work with pycrypto (if possible)?  This is just a small snip showing he encryption, I can post the entire function if needed.

```
    s = SMIME.SMIME()   
    s.load_key_bio(BIO.openfile(CERT), BIO.openfile(PUB_CERT))
    p7 = s.sign(BIO.MemoryBuffer(plaintext), flags=SMIME.PKCS7_BINARY)
    x509 = X509.load_cert_bio(BIO.openfile(settings.PAYPAL_CERT))
    sk = X509.X509_Stack()
    sk.push(x509)
    s.set_x509_stack(sk)
    s.set_cipher(SMIME.Cipher('des_ede3_cbc'))
    tmp = BIO.MemoryBuffer()
    p7.write_der(tmp)
    p7 = s.encrypt(tmp, flags=SMIME.PKCS7_BINARY)
    out = BIO.MemoryBuffer()
    p7.write(out)   
    return out.read()
```

Comment: Please let me know what Linux distro webfaction is running, the Python, OpenSSL, and SWIG versions, the exact command you tried when compiling, and the full output of the compile attempt including the error. Or if Webfaction is using Fedora Core -based servers, try the fedora_setup.sh script in the M2Crypto sources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get it to build.  Here is all you need to do to make it happen:

```
cat >> ~/.pydistutils.cfg << EOF
[build_ext]
include_dirs=/usr/include/openssl
EOF
easy_install-2.5 --install-dir=$HOME/lib/python2.5 --script-dir=$HOME/bin m2crypto
```

Answer (score 1):

pycrypto is very incomplete. It does not support the padding schemes and formats that you need. Adding support for those formats is not trivial and will require a lot of time.

Comment: is there something else that does support what is needed?

Comment: M2Crypto is a wrapper for openssl. Since openssl is widely used I'm a little surprised that building M2Crypto is not possible on your servers. I'd give it another try. There are a few alternative python wrappers for openssl, but unfortunately I have no experience with them.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to set up a virtual machine locally and duplicate enough of the webfaction server environment to build it yourself. Then upload to somewhere on your pythonpath